# Add JavaScript in an HTML tag which is in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am working on a project, where I pull JSON data which looks like this

```
    {
   "page":1,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "poster_path":"\/il9XWx5CbNd2KdDUwrcClEZiLkv.jpg",
         "adult":false,
         "overview":"Last months of World War II in April 1945. As the Allies make their final push in the European Theater, a battle-hardened U.S. Army sergeant in the 2nd Armored Division named Wardaddy commands a Sherman tank called \"Fury\" and its five-man crew on a deadly mission behind enemy lines. Outnumbered and outgunned, Wardaddy and his men face overwhelming odds in their heroic attempts to strike at the heart of Nazi Germany.",
         "release_date":"2014-10-15",
         "genre_ids":[  
            10752,
            18,
            28
         ],
         "id":228150,
         "original_title":"Fury",
         "original_language":"en",
         "title":"Fury",
         "backdrop_path":"\/pKawqrtCBMmxarft7o1LbEynys7.jpg",
         "popularity":11.717304,
         "vote_count":2435,
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.43
      },
      {  
         "poster_path":"\/adw6Lq9FiC9zjYEpOqfq03ituwp.jpg",
         "adult":false,
         "overview":"A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking new form of therapy. Their concept catches on, with underground \"fight clubs\" forming in every town, until an eccentric gets in the way and ignites an out-of-control spiral toward oblivion.",
         "release_date":"1999-10-14",
         "genre_ids":[  
            18
         ],
         "id":550,
         "original_title":"Fight Club",
         "original_language":"en",
         "title":"Fight Club",
         "backdrop_path":"\/8uO0gUM8aNqYLs1OsTBQiXu0fEv.jpg",
         "popularity":7.681482,
         "vote_count":5581,
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":8.07
      },
```

I pull this using AJAX and then I add it to a JavaScript function like this

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'themoviedb_data.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(" Page " +data.page );

            for(i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                console.log(" poster_path "+data.results[i].poster_path);
                console.log(" adult "+data.results[i].adult);
                console.log(" overview "+data.results[i].overview);
                console.log(" release_date "+data.results[i].release_date);

                for(j = 0; j < data.results[i].genre_ids.length; j++) {
                    console.log(" genre_ids "+ (j+1) +" :"+data.results[i].genre_ids[[j]]);
                }

                console.log(" id "+data.results[i].id);
                console.log(" original_title "+data.results[i].original_title);
                console.log(" original_language "+data.results[i].original_language);
                console.log(" title "+data.results[i].title);
                console.log(" backdrop_path "+data.results[i].backdrop_path);
                console.log(" popularity "+data.results[i].popularity);
                console.log(" vote_count "+data.results[i].vote_count);
                console.log(" video "+data.results[i].video);
                console.log(" vote_average "+data.results[i].vote_average);
            }
            console.log(" total_results  "+data.total_results);
            console.log(" total_pages  "+data.total_pages);
        }
    });

(function() {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:88/test-arkadium/themoviedb_data.json", false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var jsResult = JSON.parse(result);
            }
             //var image_path = jsResult.results[0].backdrop_path;
            //document.write('<img src = https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/>');

  var questions = [ {
                        //question: "This scene is from which movie?",
                    //choices: [jsResult.results[2].original_title, jsResult.results[8].original_title, jsResult.results[0].original_title, jsResult.results[4].original_title, jsResult.results[6].original_title],
                    //correctAnswer: 3
                    },
                    {
                    question: "Which Brad Pitt Movie is based on a famous novel by Chuck Palahniuk?",
                    choices: [jsResult.results[0].original_title, jsResult.results[1].original_title, jsResult.results[2].original_title, jsResult.results[3].original_title, jsResult.results[4].original_title],
                    correctAnswer: 1 }, {
                            question: "In which year was the movie se7en released?",
                    choices: [jsResult.results[1].release_date, jsResult.results[0].release_date, jsResult.results[2].release_date, jsResult.results[5].release_date, jsResult.results[6].release_date],
                    correctAnswer: 3
                    }, {
                        question: "What is the average user rating for Inglourious Basterds?",
                    choices: [jsResult.results[2].vote_average, jsResult.results[8].vote_average, jsResult.results[0].vote_average, jsResult.results[4].vote_average, jsResult.results[7].vote_average],
                    correctAnswer: 3
                    }
                    ];
```

This is a quiz I am designing. Now I want to take the backdrop_path from the json and append it to the https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/[backdrop_path], like this.

But since the following code is in JavaScript, I am unable to add image tag in the JS object and append the backdrop_path(.jpg) here.

```
question: "This scene is from which movie?{I want to add an image tag here }",
                    choices: [jsResult.results[2].original_title, jsResult.results[8].original_title, jsResult.results[0].original_title, jsResult.results[4].original_title, jsResult.results[6].original_title],
                    correctAnswer: 3
                    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just concatenate the image tag to the end of the string?

Comment: @Ryan Yes since it is a JavaScript file, I have to write the Image tag inside document.write() and it doesn't work if I try to append inside that.

Comment: Without actually seeing the HTML you've written, it's hard to give you a concrete answer, but using document.write() is certainly not the only way to inject new HTML into a document. Also, you could just use the + operator to append your tag to the end of the string before you send it to document write. Having the code in JavaScript isn't a hinderence. This is what JavaScript is for.